Typeorm Sub query is not working for getMany()
const queryBuilder = this.candidateRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('candidate')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('candidate.role_user', 'roleUser')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('candidate.candidate_status', 'candidateStatus')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('candidate.employment_type', 'employmentType')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('candidate.candidate_job', 'candidateJob')
  .select([
    'candidate.id',
    'candidate.user_id',
    'candidate.candidate_code',
    'candidate.first_name',
    'candidate.last_name',
    'candidateJob.job_id'
  ])
  .groupBy('candidate.id')
  .addGroupBy('candidateJob.job_id')
  .addSelect(subQuery => {
    return subQuery
      .subQuery()
      .select('GROUP_CONCAT(regions.name)', 'regions')
      .from(CandidateRegion, 'candidateRegions')
      .innerJoin('regions', 'regions', 'regions.id = candidateRegions.region_id')
      .where('candidateRegions.candidate_id = candidate.id');
  }, 'regions')
if (filters.keyword) {
  queryBuilder.andWhere(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb.where('candidate.full_name LIKE :search', {
          search: `%${filters.keyword}%`
        })
        .orWhere('roleUser.email LIKE :search', {
          search: `%${filters.keyword}%`
        });
    }),
  );
}

queryBuilder.andWhere('candidate.candidate_status_id != 6')
  .andWhere('candidate.is_deleted = :isDeleted', {
    isDeleted: filters.is_deleted
  })
  .andWhere('roleUser.role_id IN (:...roleIds)', {
    roleIds
  })
  .orderBy('candidate.first_name')
  .getMany();

Sub query is not returning any data when I use .getMany(). But it works for .getRawMany().
Can any one help me to fix this using .getMany()
I have tried like below aswell.
.addSelect(`(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM candidate_regions INNER JOIN regions ON regions.id = candidate_regions.region_id WHERE candidate_regions.candidate_id = candidate.id)`, 'regions');

